# How to match a pattern with Regex in C#, for the regex challenged?

Tags: c#, regex

Taking the following string example, what is the pattern I should use to extract all of the string instances I need? So, taking:

```
string Text = @"Dear {Customer.Name},
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {Customer.FirstName}";
```

And extracting `{Customer.Name}` and `{Customer.FirstName}`? As a bonus can the `{` and `}` be removed during the extraction?

I'm poking around with LinqPad, and I've got `new Regex("{[A-Za-z0-9.]+}", RegexOptions.Multiline).Match(Text)` so far, but it's only matching the first substring of `{Customer.Name}`.

I'm very challenged in regular expressions, so I'd appreciate detailed help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your regex looks fine. The only problem is, that you need to call `Matches` instead of `Match` to get all matches in the input string.

You can put the part you want to have as a result in a sub group and then use only the sub group in further processing:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(Text, "{([A-Za-z0-9.]+)}", RegexOptions.Multiline);
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    var variable = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Comment: Also it's nicer to use the static `Regex.Matches` method, as it will cache the regex rather than creating a new one each time. (You can just pass the Regex object around but that's annoying.)

Comment: lol, the `Matches` part is one of those things where you just slap yourself in the face and think how could you possibly miss that? I guess it just shows how uneducated I am with regular expressions... Anyway, thanks for the example, I tried in LinqPad and it produced exactly what I needed. Thanks again!

Comment: yeah it just hit me that I forgot to accept it after I commented. :p

Answer (score 2):

a solution look ahead and look behind, no need to use group..

```
(?<={)[^}]*(?=})
```

Comment: Certainly interesting however from code maintenance perspective horrible.

Comment: +1 @Gursel, I don't know how overkill or bad it is as far as maintenance, but I like it. I'm gonna use my pattern for now simply because I understand it, but as I learn to read yours I may use it. Thanks for the example though!

Comment: But be careful, these constructs are performance killer, if your text size is about mb sizes, I do not recommend this solution.

Comment: I would assume it's more in the KB range. Think of a document with a couple of pages.